# 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

When I am trying to update the SQL Server data to upper case from visual studio C# in asp.net I am getting this error:

> 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but
>   was not handled in user code Additional information: Incorrect syntax
>   near ','

Code

```
        String applicantSql = "SELECT applicantId, fullName, idNumber, idType, nationality, race, gender FROM applicant";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(applicantSql, connection);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //fill the datatable with data
        da.Fill(dt);
        // Decrypt / Encrypt and Convert all Data to Uppercase
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            string idNumber = dr["idNumber"].ToString();
            string dcIdNumber = c.decryptInfo(idNumber).ToUpper();
            oupdatedIdNumber = dr["idNumber"].ToString();
            oupdatedFullName = dr["fullName"].ToString();
            oupdatedIdType = dr["idType"].ToString();
            oupdatedNationality = dr["nationality"].ToString();
            oupdatedRace = dr["race"].ToString();
            oupdatedGender = dr["gender"].ToString();
            updatedIdNumber = c.encryptInfo(dcIdNumber);
            updatedFullName = dr["fullName"].ToString().ToUpper();
            updatedIdType = dr["idType"].ToString().ToUpper();
            updatedNationality = dr["nationality"].ToString().ToUpper();
            updatedRace = dr["race"].ToString().ToUpper();
            updatedGender = dr["gender"].ToString().ToUpper();
            // Update applicant Table with latest data
            string updateApplicantSql = "UPDATE applicant SET idNumber = @idNumber, fullName = @fullName, idType = @idType, nationality = @nationality, race = @race, gender = @gender";
            updateApplicantSql += " WHERE idNumber = @oidNumber AND fullName = @ofullName AND idType = @oidType AND nationality = @onationality, race = @orace, gender = @ogender";
            SqlCommand cmdUpdateApplicant = new SqlCommand(updateApplicantSql, connection);
            connection.Open();
           cmdUpdateApplicant.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idNumber", updatedIdNumber);
            cmdUpdateApplicant.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullName", updatedFullName);
            cmdUpdateApplicant.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idType", updatedIdType);
            cmdUpdateApplicant.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nationality", updatedNationality);
            cmdUpdateApplicant.Parameters.AddWithValue("@race", updatedRace);
            cmdUpdateApplicant.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", updatedGender);
            cmdUpdateApplicant.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oidNumber", oupdatedIdNumber);
            cmdUpdateApplicant.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ofullName", oupdatedFullName);
            cmdUpdateApplicant.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oidType", oupdatedIdType);
            cmdUpdateApplicant.Parameters.AddWithValue("@onationality", oupdatedNationality);
            cmdUpdateApplicant.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orace", oupdatedRace);
            cmdUpdateApplicant.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ogender", oupdatedGender);
            cmdUpdateApplicant.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Rel - don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
updateApplicantSql += " WHERE idNumber = @oidNumber AND fullName = @ofullName AND idType = @oidType AND nationality = @onationality, race = @orace, gender = @ogender";
```

to

```
updateApplicantSql += " WHERE idNumber = @oidNumber AND fullName = @ofullName AND idType = @oidType AND nationality = @onationality and race = @orace and gender = @ogender";
```

replace commas by `and`.